# strip_tags in multidimensional array

Tags: php

I find how remove html tags in dynamic multidimensional array with this :

```
function strip_tags_deep($value){
  return is_array($value) ? array_map('strip_tags_deep', $value) : strip_tags($value);
}
```

Now, I would like apply the strip_tags for only key value like this...

```
function strip_tags_deep($value){
  return is_array($value) ? array_map('strip_tags_deep', $value) : /* IF $KEY == "valuetest" THEN */ strip_tags($value);
}
```

How can I do that ?

Edit : Thx to Prisoner =)

My new function is :

```
function strip_tags_deep($value, $key = null){
  if(is_array($value)){
    return array_map('strip_tags_deep', $value, array_keys($value));
  }else{
    if($key === '#title'){
      return strip_tags($value));
    }
    return $value;
  }
}
```

But she's return an array but...(<- see edit2 bellow)
But if I do this..

```
function strip_tags_deep($value, $key = null){
  if(is_array($value)){
    return array_map('strip_tags_deep', $value);
  }else{
    //if($key === '#title'){
      return strip_tags(html_entity_decode($value));
    //}
    return $value;
  }
}
```

I have same result than my first try. Hmmm its srtangly, why there is a problem with the third argument's array_map ?

edit2 : an example array

```
"arrayvalue1"
 "arrayvalue11"
  "a" => "avalue"
  "b" => "bvalue"
  "arrayvalue111"
    "c" => "cvalue"
```

become with "'strip_tags_deep', $value, array_keys($value)" :

```
0
 0
  0 => "avalue"
  1 => "bvalue"
 1
  0 => "cvalue"
```

I lost the "array name" :/ (forgive my poor english)

Comment: to retrieve keys, you need to foreach the array

Answer (score 1):

```
function strip_tags_deep($value, $key = null){
  if(is_array($value)){
    return array_map('strip_tags_deep', $value, array_keys($value));
  }else{
    if($key === 'valuetest'){
      return strip_tags($value);
    }
    return $value;
  }
}
```

This will output:

```
var_dump(strip_tags_deep(array('valuetest'=>'test<>'))); // array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "test" }
var_dump(strip_tags_deep(array('tests'=>'test<>'))); // array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "test<>" }
```

Comment: what doesn't work? I changed test to valuetest and it strips the tag from the array?